# MySQL иерархическая модель

Tags: mysql, sql

Как можно реализовывать структуру и запрос по иерархической модели ?!

Допустим для книги "Java. Руководство для начинающих
Г. Шилдт" была бы иерархия.

Книги / Компьютеры и Интернет / Языки и системы программирования / Java

Как можно реализовывать поиск по одной из группы к примеру по "Компьютеры и Интернет" ?

но книги бывают и других жанров к примеру "Kali Linux от разработчиков" уже присутствует таблица со связью

Книги / Компьютеры и Интернет / Операционные системы / Unix, Linux, Mac OS и другие операционные системы

Comment: Скажу так - это возможно. Теперь второе - не советую делать такие выборки на стороне SQL. Лучше обрабатывать это на прикладном ЯП.
Хранить в бд древовидную структуру - элементарно, добавляете поле Parrent, и например атрибут(поле) - Folder, первый ссылается на родительский элемент(например по ID), второй сообщает что это группа или элемент(Достаточно булевого значения).

Comment: Есть [несколько](https://www.arbinada.com/ru/node/25) способов реализации иерархических структур в базах данных. Выберите наиболее подходящий, а потом уже можно думать над запросами.

Comment: Вариант @Владимир Клыков, норм, в Oracle есть даже специальная конструкция для раскрутки деревьев.

Comment: @Yaroslav если в тегах у вопроса будет стоять оракл а не MySQL - я ни слова не скажу про сложность и нагрузки древовидной выборки =) в MySQL такого нет(по крайней мере до 8.х версий), а способы достижения - очень медленные.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Я реализовавал что то подобное это по сути связанный двух направленные списки. Средствами sql можно реализовать без труда только в одно направление (сверху вниз где верх последний элемент списка) только вот я затрудняюсь с представлением того как можно снизу сделать поиск "по группам ну или тематикам"

Comment: Ровно так же как и сверху вниз, только выбирать не дочерние элементы а родительские =) Одним запросом в MySQL до версий 8 это делается через хранимую процедуру(если уровень возможной вложенности неизвестен), но такой способ очень медленный, лучше выбрать сначала все категории а потом запросом выдернуть содержимое всех категорий... Собсно говоря во втором комментарии ссылка, и там описание как это сделать есть.